# Apache Spark -- Java , Group Live Stream data

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to get live JSON data from RabbitMQ to Apache Spark using Java and do some realtime analytics out of it.

I am able to get the data and also do some basic SQL queries on it, but I am not able to figure out the grouping part.

Below is the JSON I have

```js
{"DeviceId":"MAC-101","DeviceType":"Simulator-1","data":{"TimeStamp":"26-06-2017 16:43:41","FR":10,"ASSP":20,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"ProgramNo":2,"Status":3,"Timeinmillisecs":636340922213668165}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-101","DeviceType":"Simulator-1","data":{"TimeStamp":"26-06-2017 16:43:41","FR":10,"ASSP":20,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"ProgramNo":2,"Status":3,"Timeinmillisecs":636340922213668165}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-102","DeviceType":"Simulator-1","data":{"TimeStamp":"26-06-2017 16:43:41","FR":10,"ASSP":20,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"ProgramNo":2,"Status":3,"Timeinmillisecs":636340922213668165}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-102","DeviceType":"Simulator-1","data":{"TimeStamp":"26-06-2017 16:43:41","FR":10,"ASSP":20,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"ProgramNo":2,"Status":3,"Timeinmillisecs":636340922213668165}}
```

I would like to group them by device id. The idea is that way I can run and gather analytics against individual devices. Below is the sample code snippet that I am trying

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            mconf = new SparkConf();
            mconf.setAppName("RabbitMqReceiver");
            mconf.setMaster("local[*]");

            jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(mconf,Durations.seconds(10));

            SparkSession spksess = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .master("local[*]")
                    .appName("RabbitMqReceiver2")
                    .getOrCreate();


            SQLContext sqlctxt = new SQLContext(spksess);

            JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> jsonData = jssc.receiverStream(
                    new mqreceiver(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2()));

            //jsonData.print();

            JavaDStream<String> machineData = jsonData.window(Durations.minutes(1), Durations.seconds(20));

            machineData.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {

                @Override
                public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
                    if(!rdd.isEmpty()){

                        Dataset<Row> data = sqlctxt.read().json(rdd);

                        //Dataset<Row> data = spksess.read().json(rdd).select("*");
                        data.createOrReplaceTempView("DeviceData");
                        data.printSchema();
                        //data.show(false);

                        // The below select query works
                        //Dataset<Row> groupedData = sqlctxt.sql("select * from DeviceData where DeviceId='MAC-101'");

                        // The below sql fails...

                        Dataset<Row> groupedData = sqlctxt.sql("select * from DeviceData GROUP BY DeviceId");
                        groupedData.show(); 


                    }
                }
            });

            jssc.start();

            jssc.awaitTermination();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What i am looking to do with the streamed data is to see if i can push the incoming data into individual buckets...

Lets say we have the below incoming data from rabbitmq,

What i want to do is to have either a single key/value based collection which will have the device id as key and List as value
Or it could be somekind of individual dynamic collection for each device id.

Can we do something like the below code (from url -- http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-groupby-example/)

```js
public class GroupByExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext();
            
            // Parallelized with 2 partitions
            JavaRDD<String> rddX = sc.parallelize(
                    Arrays.asList("Joseph", "Jimmy", "Tina",
                            "Thomas", "James", "Cory",
                            "Christine", "Jackeline", "Juan"), 3);
            
            JavaPairRDD<Character, Iterable<String>> rddY = rddX.groupBy(word -> word.charAt(0));
            
            System.out.println(rddY.collect());
        }
    }
```

So in our case we need to pass a filter for the group by w.r.t DeviceId

Working Code....

```js
JavaDStream<String> strmData = jssc.receiverStream(
     new mqreceiver(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2()));
   
//This is just a sliding window i have kept
JavaDStream<String> machineData = strmData.window(Durations.minutes(1), Durations.seconds(10));
machineData.print();

JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairedData = machineData.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<String, String>(s.substring(5, 10) , new String(s)));
   
JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<String>> groupedData = pairedData.groupByKey();
groupedData.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in queries with group by, only following columns can be used in select:

- columns listed in group by
- aggregation of any of column

If you use "*", then all columns are used in select - and that's why the query fails. Change the query to for example:

```
select DeviceId, count(distinct DeviceType) as deviceTypeCount from DeviceData group by DeviceId
```

and it will work, because it uses only column in group by and columns in aggregation functions

Comment: Thanks , I should have thought through about grouping logic having written lots of sql myself. 
As you suggested the query comes through obviously if you have a aggregation associated with the query.  
I have edited my question with additonal details , please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: Figured this one out, updated code in main post just in case someone is looking at the same problem.